# predict train_generator from vgg16 to compare the true value vs prediction value

Tags: python-3.x, prediction, vgg-net

I've 20 classes and 2907 observations in my train dataset of dog from imagenet.
I want to compare my predictions and the true value of label because of overfitting problems.
I try :

```
X_train, y_train = next(train_generator)
preds = net_final.predict(X_train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, verbose=0)
print(train_generator.n)
print(len(X_train))
pred_labels = np.argmax(preds, axis=1)
true_labels = np.argmax(y_train, axis=1)
print (pred_labels)
print (true_labels)
```

The problem is : train_generator.n equals 2907
and len(X_train) equals 50.

How can i recover the true label to compare to my predictions?
I'm a french student and i'm sure i make some errors in english and in python of course ;) i apologize.
Thanks for your response

Comment: I am not familiar with vgg-net but I am a bit confused as to how to help you. I feel like your issue resides in your use of the train_generator. The discrepancy between train_generator.n and len(X_train) can only come from the first line of code. How are you setting up this generator ? Also, do you understand python generators and what next() does ?
No need to apologize for your English, it's good enough and we're all in the same boat to some degree.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.